Does D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_CONSTANT require padding in ExecuteIndirect D3D12_COMMAND_SIGNATURE_DESCs?
Do the commands in ExecuteIndirect require padding if they are not 64 bit aligned? So I am implementing some calls to ExecuteIndirect and I was defining the command structure like so:
    const uint32_t dwNumCmds = 4;
    D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_DESC cmds[dwNumCmds];
    //set mesh Index offset (SetGraphicsRoot32BitConstants)
    cmds[0].Type = D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_CONSTANT;
    cmds[0].Constant.RootParameterIndex = 1;
    cmds[0].Constant.DestOffsetIn32BitValues = 0;
    cmds[0].Constant.Num32BitValuesToSet = 1;
    //set vertex buff (IASetVertexBuffers)
    cmds[1].Type = D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_VERTEX_BUFFER_VIEW;
    cmds[1].VertexBuffer.Slot = 0;
    //set index buff (IASetIndexBuffer)
    cmds[2].Type = D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_INDEX_BUFFER_VIEW;
    //drawn instances (DrawIndexedInstanced)
    cmds[3].Type = D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_DRAW_INDEXED;

    D3D12_COMMAND_SIGNATURE_DESC commandSignatureDesc;
    commandSignatureDesc.pArgumentDescs = cmds;
    commandSignatureDesc.NumArgumentDescs = dwNumCmds;
    commandSignatureDesc.ByteStride = sizeof(IndirectCommand);
    commandSignatureDesc.NodeMask = 0;

but then I go to make the equivalent struct in CPU land so I can do sizeof with it in the above COMMAND_SIGNATURE_DESC:
//reflects our command signature
struct IndirectCommand
{
    uint32_t dwMeshOffset; //cmd 0 
    // uint32_t dwPadding; //this is created implicitly by cpu alignment requirements to 64 bit because of the GPU_ADRESS from the buffer views alone
    D3D12_VERTEX_BUFFER_VIEW vertexBufferView; //cmd 1
    D3D12_INDEX_BUFFER_VIEW indexBufferView; //cmd 2
    D3D12_DRAW_INDEXED_ARGUMENTS drawArguments; //cmd 3
};

but c/c++ will auto pad between the 32-bit value and the 64-bit gpu addresses in the vertexBufferView. So my question is, does the GPU need that padding as well, or should I just count my bytes instead of doing sizeof?
thanks for the help in advance


Does D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_CONSTANT require padding in ExecuteIndirect D3D12_COMMAND_SIGNATURE_DESCs?

Yes.
As far as I'm concerned, D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_CONSTANT require padding in ExecuteIndirect D3D12_COMMAND_SIGNATURE_DESCs.
I suggest you could refer to the Doc: Indirect Drawing

the doc that you linked though says that "All of the arguments for one draw (graphics)/dispatch (compute) call within an indirect argument buffer are tightly packed." which contradicts what you are saying? Would have been nice if Microsoft put an example of this. They do also say "There is no padding between structures." which is interesting

According to the Doc:
The indirect argument buffer generated by the application would contain an array of fixed-size records.
As far as I'm concerned, the single structure within an indirect argument buffer chooses whether need to be padded or not according to ByteStride. And there is no padding between structures.
